# System.Timers.Timer and Daylight Saving Time

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone, system.timers.timer

I have some timers that read `HH:MM:SS` from a table to figure out when to run on a daily basis.

For example:
Timer A needs to run every Monday at 13:00:00
Timer B needs to run every Tuesday at 02:00:00
Timer C needs to run every hour

So in my code I figure out what the current time is and then calculate the milliseconds from `DateTime.Now()` to the next occurrence of when the timer should run. When the timer's `Elapsed` event has completed, it recalculates when it is supposed to run next. This created a problem over this weekend due to the time change.

Is there a better way to do this? Would `DateTime.UtcNow` be a better alternative? Maybe convert the time string in the database to a UTC time and then figure out the difference between `DateTime.UtcNow()` instead of `DateTime.Now()`?

Comment: Yes, UTC, but why is your date or time being stored as a string and not a date in the database?

Comment: But still, what is your notion of now. When you store the time in UTC, you will have an other run time while on DST. There is a bunch of information from this topic available, starting point would be the Hanselminutes podcast with the creator of Noda Time: http://hanselminutes.com/485/the-problem-with-datetime-nodatime-with-matt-johnson. But also http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/ is quite informative.

Comment: First, you need a specification. A _good_ one. One that covers precisely how the code should behave in various scenarios, including changing to or from DST. If you switch to UTC, none of the examples you gave should be affected by the change. So that's one option. But what about a timer that needs to run every other hour? Or a timer that needs to run at 2am every day, or 2am on Sunday? Etc. As stated, your question is far too broad, not the least of which because you haven't even completely specified the desired behaviors.

Comment: Would it be an idea to use Quartz.NET for your triggers?

Comment: Why are you talking about timers at all?  Timers are short-lived. They are not for scheduling events hours or days out.  Is this just your wording, or are you actually trying to use `System.Timers.Timer`  like question is tagged?

Answer (score -1):

You can do several things to solve this problem.

One is to use UTC for all your scheduled jobs. That gives you a robust and predictable system without a lot of complications or testing burden. But the jobs that run at 03:00 on Mondays in the summer will run at 02:00 in the winter. If that's OK, the UTC strategy is a good one.

(Testing timezone switchover use cases is a pain, and if you use UTC for everything your test burden is reduced.)

Another is to get serious with your date arithmetic, and be very careful. C#'s DateTime class does a good job of date arithmetic even on changeover dates.

So, let's say you need to run a process once a week on Sunday at 01:30. That's in the nightmare hour in the USA ... it doesn't happen in the spring changeover, and it happens twice in the fall changeover. But you still want the process to run once.

What you do is this: Keep a "next scheduled time" value. Each time you finish running the job, compute the "next scheduled time" value for the next run. This might work like this:

```
var today = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7); /* midnight a week from now */
TimeSpan runTime = TimeSpan.Parse("01:30");
var nextRun = today + runTime;
```

Then, save that nextRun DateTime value.  Later on you can figure out how long it is until the next run. This is a good way to do that. There are others.

```
var msUntilNextRun = (nextRun.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks) / 10000;
```

If the msUntilNextRun value comes up reasonably small and positive, you can sleep until it's time for the run.  If it comes up small and negative, you overslept--run immediately (oversleeping is *very* common).

Adding the days to the present midnight value, then adding the time to that, then figuring how long to wait, is a way to get a reasonable runtime even on changeover days.

Comment: Sorry, but *"C#'s DateTime class does a good job of date arithmetic even on changeover dates"* is incorrect.  `DateTime` does not take DST into account at all.  In general, never ever do math with local `DateTime` values, such as `DateTime.Now`.  Please read #1 in [Five Common Daylight Saving Time Antipatterns of .NET Developers](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/) and [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).